# alternative of Dynamic drive dropdown menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently used a http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddlevelsmenu/ in a web application.

i want to use something else who give me same facelity and something better then i replace them by removing this one.

so what's good alternative avilable who are better then ddlevelemenu and give better functionality then them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/). [Examples](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)